# Apache Beam JmsIO - Avro Serialization issues with unbounded source

Tags: apache-beam

I get the following exception when reading from unbounded JMS Source:

```
avro.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: this$0
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2234)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:225)
    ... 12 more
```

The exception is thrown by Avro when introspecting `JmsCheckpointMark` to generate schema.

JmsIO config :

```
PCollection<DFAMessage> messages = pipeline.apply("read messages from the events broker",
            JmsIO.<DFAMessage>readMessage()
                    .withConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory)
                    .withTopic(options.getTopic())
                    .withMessageMapper(new DFAMessageMapper())
                    .withCoder(AvroCoder.of(DFAMessage.class)));
```

Comment: It's an apache beam bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7427

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  Looking here, https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8757 ... it looks like you have been working on a fix.  When I try and view the link above, I get no response (may be a transient thing).  Is this bug still "cooking"?  We have a user who seems to have hit the same issue in Apache Beam 2.16.0.